# Как получить значения по атрибуту всех элементов dom-дерева?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть див с id **blocks**.
В нём есть множество элементов с тегом **item**.
У каждого элемента есть свой атрибут **material_id** с каким-то уникальным числовым значением.

**Вопрос знатокам:** как получить *в виде одной строки* все значения из *material_id*?

Пробую так:

```
console.log($('#blocks').find('item').attr('material_id'));
```

Выводится значение material_id только из первого item. :-(

Comment: item это такой тэг?

Comment: @НазарКалитюк ага

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
console.log(
  $('#blocks').find('item').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('material_id')
  }).get().join(',')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blocks">
  <item material_id="1"></item>
  <item material_id="2"></item>
  <item material_id="3"></item>
  <item material_id="4"></item>
</div>
```